# Deal with concurrent modification on List without having ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, list, java.util.concurrent

I have a stateful EJB which calls an EJB stateless method of Web parsing pages.

Here is my stateful code :

```
@Override
public void parse() {
    while(true) {
        if(false == _activeMode) {
            break;
        }
        for(String url : _urls){
            if(false == _activeMode) {
                break;
            }
            for(String prioritaryUrl : _prioritaryUrls) {
                if(false == _activeMode)
                    break;
                boursoramaStateless.parseUrl(prioritaryUrl);
            }

            boursoramaStateless.parseUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

No problem here.

I have some asynchronously call (with JMS) that add to my _urls variable (a List) some value. Goal is to parse new url inside my infinity loop.

I receive ConcurrentModificationException when I try to add new url in my List via JMS onMessage method but it seems to be working because this new url is parsed.

When I try to wrap a synchronized block :

```
while(true){
    synchronized(_url){
        // code...
    }
}
```

My new url is never parsed, I expected to be parsed after a for() loop finished...

So my question is : how can I modify List when it's accessed inside a loop without having ConcurrentModificationException please ?

I just want 2 threads to modify some shared resource at same time without synchronized block...

Comment: How do you read the List? If you don't use an iterator, it should ignore concurrent modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: @OlivierJ. you need to make sure u understand the problems with CopyOnWriteArrayList as well . If you vahe lots of writes and less numbers of reads , then the CopyOnWriteArrayList  will not be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

First, forget about `synchronized` when running into Java EE container. It bothers the container to optimize threads utilization and will not work in clustered environment.

Second, it seems that your design is wrong. You should not update private field of the bean using JMS. This thing causes `ConcurrentModificationException`. You probably should modify your bean to retrieve the collection from database and your MDB to store the URL into the Database.

Other, easier for you solution is the following.
Retrieve the currently existing URLs and copy them to other collection. Then iterate over this collection. When the global collection is updated via JMS the update is not visible in the copied collection, so no exceptions will be thrown:

```
while(true) {
    for (String url : copyUrls(_prioritaryUrls)) {
       // deal with url
    }
}

private List<String> copyUrls(List<Stirng> urls) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(urls); // this create copy of the source list
}


//........
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    _prioritaryUrls.add(((TextMessage)message).getText());
}
```

Comment: The copy and modification of _prioritaryUrls can still be concurrent and throw an exception, unless the list is defined as a `Collections.synchronizedList()` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`For (String s : urls)` uses an Iterator internally. The iterator checks for concurrent modification so that its behavior is well defined.

You can use a `for(int i= ...` loop. This way, no exception is thrown, and if elements are only added to the end of the List, you still get a consistent snapshot (the list as it exists at some time during the iteration). If the elements in the list are moved around, you may get missing entries.

If you want to use `synchronised`, you need to synchronise on both ends, but that way you lose concurrent reads.

If you want concurrent access AND consistent snapshots, you can use any of the collections in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.
`CopyOnWriteArrayList` has already been mentioned. The other interesting are `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ArrayBlockingQueue` (`Collection`s but not `List`s) but that's about all.

Answer (score 0):

ok thank you guys.

So I made some modifications.

1) added iterator and leaving synchronized block (inside parse() function and around addUrl() function which add new url to my List)
--> it's work like a charm, no ConcurrentModificationException launched

2) added iterator and removed synchronized blocks 
--> ConcurrentModificationException is still launched...

For now, I will read more about your answers and test your solutions.

Thank you again guys